# Select Statement Results Side by Side

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What I am trying to do is combine two select statements (which should always have the same amount of rows and columns) side by side instead of adding them together. What I have tried is a `union all`:

```
SELECT Name,Price As 'Monday' FROM tbl_checktable WHERE (Type = 3042) And CloseDate = '2015-02-09'
Union All
SELECT Name,Price As 'Tuesday' FROM tbl_checktable WHERE (Type = 3042) And CloseDate = '2015-02-10'
```

But ofcourse I get them combined linear

```
Name | Monday

Name | Value

Name | Value
```

What I am trying to Achieve is this

```
Name | Monday | Tuesday

Name | Value | Value
```

Edit: How to avoid results for tuesday being removed when there is no corresponding value for monday?

```
SELECT m.Name, m.Price AS 'Monday', t.Price as 'Tuesday', w.Price as 'Wed'
   FROM tbl_checktable m 
LEFT JOIN tbl_checktable t on m.name = t.name 
LEFT JOIN tbl_checktable w on m.name = w.name 
   WHERE (m.Type=3042 ) AND m.CloseDate ='2015-02-09'
    AND  (t.Type=3042 ) AND t.CloseDate='2015-02-10'
    AND  (w.Type=3042 ) AND w.CloseDate='2015-02-11'
```

Comment: Which rdbms platform are you using?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Sqlserver 2008, sorry

Answer (score 4):

I think `PIVOT` is best suited to the problem you are trying to solve:

```
SELECT Name, 
       [2015-02-09] AS Monday, [2015-02-10] AS Tuesday, [2015-02-11] AS Wednesday
FROM (
   SELECT Name, Price, CloseDate 
   FROM tbl_checktable
   WHERE Type = 3042) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
   AVG(Price)
   FOR CloseDate IN ([2015-02-09], [2015-02-10], [2015-02-11])
) AS PivotTable;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/055d2/2)

Comment: @Saba How does this work when Name returns multiple values though? When I change your example to 'a','b','c' instead of 'a','a','a' it only returns 2 rows, expected 3

Comment: @clamchoda This is not true. Check this SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1549/1

Comment: Ah, I wondered if sql-server had PIVOT.  I actually haven't used sql-server *or* PIVOT in the context of SQL, but I'm aware of it from spreadsheets.

Answer (score 2):

It does the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT Name, Price, DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CloseDate) as dayn
    FROM tbl_checktable 
    WHERE [Type] = 3042
    AND CloseDate IN ('02/16/2015', '02/17/2015') 
) d
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Price) for dayn IN (Monday, Tuesday)
) piv;
```

add Wednesday, Thursday, etc based on your need

Comment: Caveat: This will only work once you have two or more dates that fall on the same day. The would be lumped together in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use a JOIN instead of UNION.

```
SELECT m.Name, m.Price AS 'Monday', t.Price as 'Tuesday'
   FROM tbl_checktable m OUTER JOIN tbl_checktable t on m.name = t.name 
   WHERE m.Type=3042 AND m.CloseDate ='2015-02-09'
    AND  t.Type=3042 AND t.CloseDate='2015-02-10';
```

Comment: Why did this answer get down voted... it seems to be exactly what I need?

Comment: I'm also hate down voting without any comment, as I am the only other person who answered this question, please don't think the downvote is from me.

Comment: @Daniel Please see my edit, how come when I add in wed, my results are no longer there?

Comment: @clamchoda LEFT JOIN is not the right choice, you will lose Tuesday if there is no corresponding value for Monday.

Comment: @Daniel I tried switching to LEFT OUTER JOIN and still my data disappears when there is no corresponding value

Comment: Farhang Amary 'Ferhęg' answer works for you. Isn't it?

Comment: No "LEFT", just OUTER

Comment: @Saba No, It gives me two rows

Comment: @Daniel Just OUTER Join gives me syntax near keyword JOIN, FULL OUTER JOIN also gives me same result :(

Comment: Do you absolutely have to do this in SQL? It would probably be a lot simpler to do post-processing to put into the tabular form you want.

Comment: @Daniel Yes because its the datasource for an RDLC report. Thank you for your help and effort though, was very close!

Answer (score 0):

just use `case` statement:

```
SELECT Name,case CloseDate  
when '2015-02-09' then Price else null end As Monday,
case CloseDate  
when '2015-02-10' then Price else null end As Tuesday
 FROM tbl_checktable WHERE (Type = 3042) and CloseDate  in ('2015-02-09','2015-02-10')
```

Comment: Amary 'Ferheg' This is close, how do I stop name from showing up twice and just have one row though?

Comment: This creates two rows, the original request was for one row.

Comment: @Daniel I didn't down vote your answer, but I think you did, anyway

Comment: Your answer isn't the right answer, it's nothing personal.

Comment: @Daniel, only "isn't the right answer" can not be an acceptable reason for down voting as you see it's useful even if a little, as you see in first comment the question owner said "it's closed"

Comment: and also please notice to tooltip appears on the down voting icon

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you're asking for but I think there's a much better way of handling this.

```
SELECT
   min(case when m.CloseDate = '2015-02-09' then m.Price else null end) as Monday,
   min(case when m.CloseDate = '2015-02-10' then t.Price else null end) as Tuesday,
   min(case when m.CloseDate = '2015-02-11' then w.Price else null end) as Wednesday
   FROM tbl_checktable m, tbl_checktable t, tbl_checktable w
   WHERE
         m.Type = 3042 AND m.CloseDate = '2015-02-09'
     AND t.Type = 3042 AND t.CloseDate = '2015-02-10'
     AND w.Type = 3042 AND w.CloseDate = '2015-02-11'
```

You really don't need those joins and I'm wondering also why you did left joins:

```
SELECT
   min(case when m.CloseDate = '2015-02-09' then m.Price else null end) as Monday,
   min(case when m.CloseDate = '2015-02-10' then m.Price else null end) as Tuesday,
   min(case when m.CloseDate = '2015-02-11' then m.Price else null end) as Wednesday
FROM tbl_checktable as m 
WHERE
        m.Type = 3042
    AND m.CloseDate IN ('2015-02-09', '2015-02-10', '2015-02-11')
```